# How to install ssh2 on Centos?

Tags: linux, centos7, php-7.3, ssh2

I want to install ssh2 on Linux server, with Centos 7 and PHP 7.3

Tried following steps:

1. yum install gcc php-devel libssh2 libssh2-devel php-pear make
2. pecl install -f ssh2

Step 2 gave make error

[Step 2 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIaux.png)

[Step 2 error p2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6AzF.png)

Here are some of the errors

```
/var/tmp/ssh2/ssh2.c:312:2: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_fin                                                                             d'
  if (zend_hash_find(ht, method, method_len + 1, (void**)&value) == FAILURE) {
  ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/Zend/zend.h:32:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:33,
                 from /var/tmp/ssh2/ssh2.c:25:
                 ^
/var/tmp/ssh2/ssh2.c: In function 'php_ssh2_session_connect':
/var/tmp/ssh2/ssh2.c:338:2: error: too few arguments to function 'php_network_co                                                                             nnect_socket_to_host'
  socket = php_network_connect_socket_to_host(host, port, SOCK_STREAM, 0, &tv, N                                                                             ULL, NULL, NULL, 0 TSRMLS_CC);
  ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/ext/standard/file.h:22:0,
                 from /var/tmp/ssh2/ssh2.c:27:
/var/tmp/ssh2/ssh2.c:374:3: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_fin                                                                             d'
   if (zend_hash_find(HASH_OF(methods), "client_to_server", sizeof("client_to_se                                                                             rver"), (void**)&container) == SUCCESS &&
   ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/Zend/zend.h:32:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:33,
                 from /var/tmp/ssh2/ssh2.c:25:
/usr/include/php/Zend/zend_hash.h:166:30: note: declared here
 ZEND_API zval* ZEND_FASTCALL zend_hash_find(const HashTable *ht, zend_string *k                                                                             ey);
                              ^

/var/tmp/ssh2/ssh2.c:390:3: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_fin                                                                             d'
   if (zend_hash_find(HASH_OF(methods), "server_to_client", sizeof("server_to_cl                                                                             ient"), (void**)&container) == SUCCESS &&
   ^
In file included from /usr/include/php/Zend/zend.h:32:0,
                 from /usr/include/php/main/php.h:33,
                 from /var/tmp/ssh2/ssh2.c:25:

/var/tmp/ssh2/ssh2.c:496:46: error: macro "add_assoc_string" passed 4 arguments,                                                                              but takes just 3
  add_assoc_string(return_value, "kex", kex, 1);
```

Comment: Why would you screenshot text instead of copy and pasting it?

Comment: Best might be to put just the command and error in your question with a link to the full text in pastebin or something similar.

Comment: @ZanLynx I have updated my question with  some of the error, please check.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on same system. Here I did and installed ssh2 successfully.

1. Install neccessary packages:

   - `[root@lepc ~]# yum -y install make gcc glibc-devel zlib-devel openssl-devel`
   - `[root@lepc ~]# yum -y install --enablerepo=epel,remi,remi-php73 php-devel`
2. Install libssh2:

   - `[root@lepc ~]# wget https://www.libssh2.org/download/libssh2-1.9.0.tar.gz`
   - `[root@lepc ~]# tar vxzf libssh2-1.9.0.tar.gz`
   - `[root@lepc ~]# cd libssh2-1.9.0`
   - `[root@lepc ~]# ./configure`
   - `[root@lepc ~]# make`
   - `[root@lepc ~]# make install`
3. Install ssh2 from pecl:

   - `[root@lepc ~]# wget https://pecl.php.net/get/ssh2-1.2.tgz`
   - `[root@lepc ~]# tar vxzf ssh2-1.2.tgz`
   - `[root@lepc ~]# cd ssh2-1.2`
   - `[root@lepc ~]# phpize`
   - `[root@lepc ~]# ./configure --with-ssh2`
   - `[root@lepc ~]# make`
   - `[root@lepc ~]# make install`
4. Enable ssh2 extension in PHP 7.3:

   - `[root@lepc ~]# echo "extension=ssh2.so" > /etc/php.d/ssh2.ini`
     Or if there isn't any file ssh2.ini there, you can do:
   - `[root@lepc ~]# echo "extension=ssh2.so" > /etc/php.d/php.ini`
5. Check if extension is available

   - `[root@lepc ~]# php -m | grep ssh2`
   - `[root@lepc ~]# ssh2`

   Or another way:

   - `[root@lepc ~]# ls /usr/lib64/php/modules/ | grep ssh2.so`
   - `[root@lepc ~]# ssh2.so`

Maybe late but hope this will help someone.

Comment: If you use my repo, you don't have to build anything, as the php-ppecl-ssh2 package exists....

Comment: I tried it then `No package php-ppecl-ssh2 available`.

Comment: typo.... php-pecl-ssh2

https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php73/x86_64/repoview/php-pecl-ssh2.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to go double check this but I expect you have a wrong version of PHP for that library PHP wrapper.